# d3.behavior.zoom stop scalling after a specific zoom level hit

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to the world of d3 and I need to implement zooming on an svg element.

This is working as expected but what I want to do is cancel the pan behaviour once you have zoomed so far in. my scale extent is 1 - 5 so when at 1 or 5 I want the pan to be disabled. is there a way of doing this.
I have seen that calling

```
.on('mousedown.zoom',null);
```

after the .call(zoom) stops panning, but it stops it completely.

Any ideas?

Cheers
MarK

Comment: You would need to run the above code conditionally when a specific zoom level is reached, adding the handler back when the zoom level changes.

Comment: how could i re-add the handler back with the default d3 pan functionality?

Comment: You can probably just save the handler function and reset that (call `.on("mousedown.zoom")` to get the function).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Seems like a good candidate for an answer

Comment: Thanks ill give that a go. What would i have to put the listener on to detect the zoom level? Would it be on the on mouse wheel and touch event? If so how do i bubble the event so the base does what it needs to as well. Cheers

Comment: No, you can do all of that in the zoom handler function.

Comment: Ah brilliant will give it ago when back in work. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions Lars Kotthoff put in the comments above pointed me in the right direction. In then end i went with handling what needed to be handled in the zoom handler function as he recommended.

Cheers
Mark